# Please help me to focus input field in the instagram web

Tags: javascript, web, instagram

I want to achieve following algorithm:

Preconditions:

1. You are logged in instagram web version
2. You see the default home page
3. You are using chrome
4. It should be done via console tab in chrome

Task:

1. Do in vanilla JS the focus of the input field with a recommendation window
   [image]
   i.e
2. Focus the field, input cats, submit it and see the recommendation window

```html
let search = document.querySelectorAll('[placeholder="Поиск"]')[0];
search.focus();
search.click();
```

Expected behaviour:

1. Search input found
2. Search input focused
3. Recommendation popup appeared

Actual behaviour:

1. Search input found
2. Search input not focused

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Please provide more context and what source code you have accomplished to write so far. Are you trying to make a browser-extension or this is just a script that you want to execute through the browser-console (dev tools)?

Comment: I want to execute it right in the dev tools, console tab